# Deriving (Gaussian) curvature bounds from bounds on the metric

Tags: riemannian-geometry, mp.mathematical-physics, curvature, general-relativity

I am trying to understand a bound in Christodoulou's 2008 paper on [black hole formation](https://arxiv.org/abs/0805.3880).

The paper considers a spacelike surface $S$ diffeomorphic to a sphere, with two metrics:

- the induced metric $\bar{g}$ from the spacetime metric $g$, and
- a reference metric $h$ on $S$ such that $(S, h)$ is the standard sphere of radius $R$.

The paper defines a $C^k$ norm to measure the difference between $\bar{g}$ and $h$ and derives a bound of the form
$$
\|R^{-2}\bar{g} - h\|_{C^k} \leq R^{-1}F_k(M_k),
$$
where $F_k$ is a continuous, non-decreasing, nonnegative function, and $M_k$ is a constant (depending only on $k$) related to the first $k$ derivatives of the metric.
The author then claims that this implies a bound of the form
$$
\|\bar{K} - R^{-2}\|_{C^k} \leq R^{-3} F_k(M_{k + 2}),
$$
where $\bar{K}$ is the Gaussian curvature of the sphere $(S, \bar{g})$, and the constant $M_k$ is changed to $M_{k + 2}$ to reflect that curvature involves up to 2 derivatives of the metric.

How does he derive this estimate? Is it just a computation of the Gaussian curvature in coordinates via Christoffel symbols? Is there a general strategy to estimate difference in curvature in terms of difference between the metrics?